# Downloading background data for offline use android

Tags: android, multithreading, service, runnable

I have developed an `application` for one of our clients. It has a feature to use the app in offline. I have done that by saving all the data in `SQLite` DB when the app is opened every time. Data is fetched using `retrofit`. It is also downloading images(almost 300 images). I have put the code for downloading and saving in `runnable threads`. First I am calling `intent service` which is further calling the `runnable thread`. But the problem is every time it downloads data, it slows down the application. When I comment the background data downloading app works fine. I am confused as how to handle this scenario. How to download a large chunk of data without making the app unresponsive in the background. Any help is appreciated. Any other way to handle this download and syncing of data.Thanks!!

Comment: Instead of downloading all data simultaneously. Download data on each activity, which is gonna to be used.

Comment: Why do you need to download all the images? You can't save only the ones the user has viewed?

Comment: for offline use, i have to download data at once.

Comment: And instead of `sqlite db`, try to use `realm db`. Realm db is more better than `sqlite`

Comment: Yeah but the data changes? Otherwise why not add the images directly into the app?

Comment: App needs to be used in offline mode that's why downloading all the data

Comment: Images can change time to time. So data needs to be updated

Comment: Im doing almost the same but showing Progress Popup and using ASyncTask for that. Works very well for me and all downloads of Data. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Idk what is your app but generally you save only what the user has already viewed, so you don't need to download everything in the background. Depending how big are your data it can be very bad to the user as it's gonna used a lot of network data.

Comment: It has to be used for offline also, so that's why downloading all the data at once

Comment: Another way to do that could be to download everything first time (warning the user and asking him if he wants to do that on wifi only) and then, update only what has changed. (Don't need to download 300 images if only one has changed)

Comment: isn't there any efficient way to download all the data in the background without making the app unresponsive? if I directly use intent service to do all the operations then also app is unresponsive.

Comment: I have put check for images, but then also it check every time if images is already downloaded or not

Comment: As you said you need to download everything first time, what you could do is to display a loading screen and the user can't do anything but wait for the app to be initialized. You can expect the app to set up itself on first launch (as a user) so it could be ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162509/discussion-between-paras-watts-and-eselfar).

Comment: Everytime user opens app it hits the API using retrofit and saves all the data in DB again and in that process, it also checks for images whether they exist or not on the local storage. So to check for so many files also makes it unresponsive.

Comment: Are you sure you are on a different thread? Can you please post some code?